# How to remove a part of a moving object from a video?

Tags: video

I have a video in which I want to remove part of an object in every frame and then render the video again. I have tried photoshop and after effect. Both of them work somehow, but they degrade video quality significantly. Is there any other options to do it with a good quality?

Comment: The problem is that your source is compressed, reompression is a big problem. However also how you comporess is a problem just slapping some compression on has this effect on things. You need to work on your compression settings quite a bit.

Comment: What is going in the place of the part of the object you are removing?  Is it a static shot?  What do you mean by the quality being degraded?